# I can't select only 1 item due to condition Angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, compiler-errors, dialog, conditional-statements

I have the following condition: the data of 2 columns must be compared in 2 rows. If there are more than 2 rows there is no problem because the condition lets me pass it, but if I only select 1 row I get an error. I appreciate if you help me improve my condition!

**TS**

```
procesarClic() {
    const request = this.selection.selected;        
    for (let i = 0; i < request.length; i++){
      const insumoFila = request[i].insumo;
      const tipoGastoFila = request[i++].tipoGasto;
      const insumoFila2 = request[i].insumo;
      const tipoGastoFila2 = request[i++].tipoGasto;
      if (tipoGastoFila !== tipoGastoFila2 &&
        insumoFila !== insumoFila2 &&
          request.length < 3) {
            swal.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: '¡Error!',
              text: 'Please review your Insumo',
              showCancelButton: true,
              cancelButtonColor: '#00945e',
              cancelButtonText: 'Cerrar',
              showConfirmButton: false,
              allowOutsideClick: false,
              allowEscapeKey: false
            });              
          return request
      }
      else {
        const newTable = this.dialog.open(SolicitudCdpDialog, {
          width: '400px',
          disableClose: true,
          data: { datosItem:request }
        });
        return newTable
      }
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Why you do this in some of the value asignation variables? : request[i++], instead of request[i]

Comment: Because I do that to make the comparison with the other row. I compare 2 rows with some values of 2 columns. In 'request' is the data that I am going to compare. request[i++] would be row 2.

Comment: In order to get better help from us, it would be good that you will edit your answer and write the result of a console.log(request) located just before the for;

Comment: Request contains an array with 16 columns. Each column, depending on whether or not I select it with the mat-checkbox, will bring the corresponding information. Doing a console.log to request would bring up a lot of data. I am only comparing with 2 columns: "Ttipo Gasto" and "Insumo".